# theoretical and observed word probabilities disagreement

Tags: probability, word-problem, combinatorics-on-words

I am missing something obvious but cannot get an hand on it.

I want to compute the probabilities of words with particular features to appear by change.

Given a set of three characters {A, B, " "} I want to compute for each word starting and finishing by 'A' their probabilities.

A word is defined by X randomly sampled letters with  N spaces before and M spaces after, or starting and finishing at the end of a sentence, and N and M being superior or equal to 1. A word must also start and end with the letter "A". Every other sequence of characters are discarded and not taken into account.

The characters don't have the same probabilities to appear:

P(x="A") = 0.3

P(x="B") = 0.6

P(x=" ") = 0.1

I generate 10000 sentences of length 160 (it's setup arbitrarily). I run the simulation twice and observed, as expected, some slight change between the observed probabilities.

From the datasets I observed:

P(w="A") = 0.27 / 0.25

P(w="AA") = 0.078 / 0.077

P(w="ABA") = 0.043 / 0.048

...

My problem is to compare them with the theoretical probability.
If I applied the formula:

P(w=X) = 0.3^("A" \in X) * 0.6^("B" \in X)

The proba becomes quite different:

P(w="A") = 0.27 / 0.25 / 0.3

P(w="AA") = 0.078 / 0.077 / 0.3^2 = 0.09

P(w="ABA") = 0.043 / 0.048 / 0.3^2 * 0.7 = 0.054

Is it something that I should expect?
Or, am I missing something obvious (my guess)?

Comment: I don't understand why you're seeing so many "A" words.  They should be comparatively rare, since the probability of a space is so low ($0.1$).  Only $10$ percent of words should be single-letter words as a result.  Are you sure you've defined the problem properly?  (By the way, the tag (word-problem) means a problem expressed primarily in words instead of symbols, not a problem *about* words.  I'll leave it for the moment, though.)

Comment: @Brian sorry I forgot to mention something. Only sequences of letters starting and ending with "A" are considered as words. Every word starting or ending with "B" is discarded (I edited my question). Thinking about it, it's perhaps where the difference come from as the probability space become smaller.

Comment: @joriki My generated sequences look like that: "ABBBAB ABBAA BBAABBBBABBAABBABBBBBA BBBBBBABABBABAAB BBB BBBABBBBBABB BBA  BBBABAB ABB BBBBBBBBBBBA BAAB AABA BAAAAABB BABABBB BABAB  BBABBBBABABBABBBB BBBABBAA". From these sequences I split each words based on the " " characters and only take into account words starting and ending by "A"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzing the words from the beginning, we can take the initial A as given. We then have a probability $0.1$ of generating the admissible word $A$ if a space follows, and a probability $0.9\cdot\frac{0.3}{0.3+0.6}=0.3$ of generating an admissible word if a letter follows (with $\frac{0.3}{0.3+0.6}$ being the probability that the letter preceding the space that will eventually occur is an A). Thus the probability of forming an admissible word, starting with an initial A, is $0.4$, so you need to divide the unconditional probability of forming a word by $0.4$ to obtain its conditional probability among admissible words.

For instance, the word A has unconditional probability $0.1$, so its conditional probability is $\frac{0.1}{0.4}=\frac14$. Similarly, AA has unconditional probability $0.3\cdot0.1=0.03$, so its conditional probability is $\frac{0.03}{0.4}=0.075$, and ABA has unconditional probability $0.6\cdot0.3\cdot0.1=0.018$, so its conditional probability is $\frac{0.018}{0.4}=0.045$. All of these are in agreement with your observations.

If you want to calculate further probabilities, you can simplify things a bit by noting that there's always a factor $0.3\cdot0.1=0.03$ from the final A and space, so you can combine those with the denominator into a factor $\frac{0.3\cdot0.1}{0.4}=0.075$ by which you have to multiply the product of the probabilities of all the "internal" letters (the ones other than the initial and final A) to get the conditional probability of a word among the admissible words.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly.